# What is the Tor Project's "content policy"? Where is it explained?

Tags: spoofing

In [ticket #3809 "Remove referer spoofing support"](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/3809), mikeperry wrote:

> Referer spoofing breaks browser navigation due to an interaction with
>   our content policy.

What is the Tor Project's "content policy"? Where is it explained? I did search before asking.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're misunderstanding the term "content policy". It is not about what kind of content is alloweed/welcome when using Tor or about censorship. Instead, it is a technical term that describes how content in browser tabs interacts with content from other tabs and windows. The Tor Project does not have a content policy.